# Computing percentile ratio from Survey of Consumer Finance data

Tags: r, percentile, inequality

I know there is a package called `survey` doing similar things. I do not know if there is any code or way to compute percentile ratio in R.

What I would like to get is the relative net worth held by top x% of households. So it will be the ratio:

- (Top x percentile household's total wealth (0.99 quantile to max) / (total wealth in the economy)*

I found `svrqsr` in `survey` package but it gives me relative share, compared with lower 20 percentile households.

Any suggestion, or code reference that I can use?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on making a reproducible post that folks can easily answer. I'm guessing without being able to see your data or code, but does `quantile` in base R not work for your purposes?

Comment: I noticed that I can use svylorenz to compute the numbers. I am trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

follow the directions on http://asdfree.com/survey-of-consumer-finances-scf.html until you get to

```
library(convey)
scf_design$designs <- lapply( scf_design$designs , convey_prep )
```

then use

```
scf_MIcombine( with( scf_design , svyqsr( ~ networth , alpha1 = 0.01 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @camille said, `quantile` can give you your threshold(in your case, net worth of the 99 percentile household). After that, it's just a matter of summing the values greater than than the threshold.

```
amt<-10^rnorm(1e5,4,1) # Assuming a log normal distribution
amt_99<-amt[amt>quantile(amt,0.99)]  #Top 1%
sum(amt_99)/sum(amt)  # Relative net worth
#Output : [1] 0.4521971
```